# SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL when using gsoap with openssl 1.1

Tags: c++, soap, openssl, wsdl, gsoap

I am using `gsoap` (`stdsoap2.cpp`) for my application to connect to a server. We are using `openssl-1.1`, so with a minor change in `stdsoap2.cpp` (*replacing M_ASN1_STRING_data with ASN1_STRING_get0_data*), the app compiled successfully with `openssl-1.1`.
However, when trying to connect, `gsoap` gives error :

```
SOAP 1.1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
"SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL
Error observed by underlying SSL/TLS BIO: Success"
Detail: SSL_connect error in tcp_connect()
```

When investigated, it was found that in gsoap, `SSL_connect()` returns -1.
But when using `openssl-1.0`, it connects successfully.

What could be the reason ?

Using gsoap version: 2.8.23

Comment: Version 2.8.23 is old and does not support the newer OpenSSL 1.1 API.

Comment: @Dr.AlexRE Yes I understand. Can you explain with brief reason behind this error. Is there any way to apply a small patch in stdsoap2.cpp (related to BIO or anything) which can work this out ?